# What does javascript: does in iframe src?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, frameset-iframe

```
   <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

I would like to ask what did "javascript:" does in iframe src? I came across this code in a web application.

Basically, what i like about that is that they loaded body content via iframe -> like that google is doing. Does javascript: plays an important part?

E.g. http://www.webapplication.com/#Dashboard:142
Load content from dashboard.php / 142 is userid

E.g. http://www.webapplication.com/#settings:142
Load content from settings.php / 142 is userid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
javascript:''
```

does absolutely nothing, it is used as a filler. Some use about:blank, or just an empty file, and this is another way.

Answer (score 0):

I just built this demo to answer another question: http://jsfiddle.net/JCpgY/

Used in src, javascript allows you to directly inject html strings in the iframe. As far as I know this is supported by all major browsers.

In your case it just allows to assign an empty value to src (this is mandatory). The author could also have used `about:blank` or `javascript:void 0`.